# Comparison of value variations between a modeled (real) phenomena and a lot of simulated (hypothetical) phenomena, has any formal name in statistics?

Tags: probability, inference, modeling, simulation

An eruption has emitted ash into the atmosphere and this ash has fallen and covered an area of the earth with a given volume. Just to simplify the problem, imagine an area in the form of an ellipse (ellipsoid?) of x = 50 000 m; y = 20 000 m; but with a very small value for z = 1 m. There are numerical models that emulate the dynamics of ash and how it is distributed over the earth after eruptions. These models give as a result a covered area of the earth in the form of a continuous grid of values of z (let's say this value varies between 0.5 an 1.5 m). This model has some inherent errors and does not give perfectly the area of the land that was covered by the actual ash. But anyway, this error can be quantified, and we can calibrate the model to give less and less error in the results.

Then, with the model already calibrated (with very low errors), I want, for example, to see how the model behaves when I use other input parameters and simulate a lot of times stochastically. This would be a simulation by using at least 100 different values of wind over 6 hours (wind moves ash in the atmosphere). These simulations give me as a result the possible areas that would be covered by this ash. For example, suppose that one of the simulations will result in that the ash would cover the earth with an ellipse shape but with different values as the model, say x = 40 000 km; y = 25 000 km; and z = 1 m (both volumes are 1e9 m^3, or 1 000 000 000 m^3). The second simulation will give other values for x and y, and so on until the 100 simulations are done.

Now, beyond the volume being held constant:

1. Can the 100 areas resulting from the simulations be compared to the 1 area resulting by the model?
2. Do you know what a comparison between the simulation results and the model result would be called?

I'm having some problems trying to understand if this comparison between a modeled (real) phenomena and a simulated (hypothetical) phenomena, has any formal name in statistics.

Comment: This sounds like [Inference for Deterministic Simulation Models: The Bayesian Melding Approach](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2669764?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the edits @kjetilbhalvorsen, I will look into the paper you cited.